# Instantiating python dataframe in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a condition using for loop and if statement for a python dataframe object. In order to accurately specify which row from the data table to extract upon a specific condition, I searched the row index, and created an argument to specify the location before the for loop. The specifics looks something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

input_csv_file = "./CSV/Officers_and_Shareholders.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_file, skiprows=10, on_bad_lines='skip')
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
# df.drop([0, 3], inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Nama', 'Jabatan', 'Alamat', 'Klasifikasi Saham', 'Jumlah Lembar Saham', 'Total']

# print(df.shape)
# print(df.columns)
# print(df.iloc[:53])

# shareholders = df.iloc[24:42]
# print(shareholders)

# officers = df.iloc[0:23]
# print(officers)

dataframe = df.query("Total.ne('-')")

def get_shareholder_by_row_index():
    for column in df.columns:
        if object(df.iloc[column][:53]) == dataframe:
            shareholders = df.iloc[24:42]
            print(shareholders)
        # elif object(df[:53][column]) != dataframe:
        #     officers = df.iloc[0:23]
        #     print(officers)
```

Because the format of the [CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RzfqFE2Xz2VisxxvLhzoNqF6ehW8fv1R/view?usp=sharing) is not proper, I forced dataframe to re-create a header on top of the original CSV file, which I indicate under df.columns. The **df.iloc[24:42]** and **df.iloc[0:23]** are able to specifically locate the data range in the dataframe, but it doesn't return so when instantiated inside the for loop. Objectively, I want to create a function where *if the row under the column Total is empty (-), then return the officers*, but *if the row under the column Total is not empty, then return shareholders*. In this case, how should I modify the for loop and the if statement?

The desired output for shareholders will be:

```
24       PT CTCORP INFRASTRUKTUR D INDONESIA,  ...  Rp. 3.200.000.000
25                              Nomor SK :- I  ...                   
26      JalanKaptenPierreTendeanKavling12-14A  ...                   
27              PT INTRERPORT PATIMBAN AGUNG,  ...  Rp. 2.900.000.000
28                                Nomor SK :-  ...                   
29                                             ...                   
30                                             ...                   
31                                             ...                   
32                                             ...                   
33                                             ...                   
34                  PT PATIMBAN MAJU BERSAMA,  ...  Rp. 2.900.000.000
35                             Nomor SK :AHU-  ...                   
36                0061318.AH.01.01.TAHUN 2021  ...                   
37              Tanggal SK :30 September 2021  ...                   
38                                             ...                   
39                                             ...                   
40                      PT TERMINAL PETIKEMAS  ...  Rp. 1.000.000.000
41                                  SURABAYA,  ...                   
42                                Nomor SK :-  ...
```

and for the officers, it will return:

```
                                         Nama  ...              Total
1                       NIK: 3171060201830005  ...                   
2                       NPWP: 246383541071000  ...                   
3               TTL: Jakarta, 02 Januari 1983  ...                   
5                       NIK: 1271121011700003  ...                   
6                       NPWP: 070970173112000  ...                   
7                TTL: Bogor, 10 November 1970  ...                   
8                         ARLAN SEPTIA ANANDA  ...                   
9                                      RASAM,  ...                   
10                      NIK: 3174051209620003  ...                   
11                      NPWP: 080878200013000  ...                   
12                 TTL: Jakarta, 12 September  ...                   
13                                       1962  ...                   
15                      NIK: 3171011605660004  ...                   
16                      NPWP: 070141650093000  ...                   
17                  TTL: Jakarta, 16 Mei 1966  ...                   
18                                FUAD RIZAL,  ...                   
21  PURNOMO, UTAMA RASRINIK: 3578032408610001  ...                   
22                      NPWP: 097468813615000  ...                   
23               TTL: SLEMAN, 24 Agustus 1961  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stakeholder and Officer will be printed withrecpect to the index (Row Number)
if this is not the desired answer then mention little detail

```
def get_shareholder_by_row_index():
    for i in range(len(df)): 
# this will give you shareholders if row under Total is empty else office if row is not empty 
        if df["Total"][i] == '' :
            print(i," shareholders")
            print(df.iloc[i])
            # what ever your code is, will be here
        else:
            print(i," officers")
            print(df.iloc[i])

            # what ever your code is, will be here

# this will give you the indces where row under total is empty
    print(df["Total"].iloc[:53][df["Total"] == ''])
```

Comment: Yup, I added the desired dataframe output.

Comment: The dataframe you want to instantiate in both condition, call it under `print(i," shareholders")` and `print(i," officers")`